# Insufficient Privileges on Profile Detail Page

Tags: profile, summer-15

I am system administrator in developer sandbox. When I redirect to Profile detail of current user or any other users got "Insufficient Privileges" error page. One more thing there no option in global search box for Profile. I am not confirm but I think some updates of Summer 15 release is effecting this. Please share your thoughts, if you find something corrections.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In professional edition we dont have profile. While signing up for salesforce you may get professional edition environment for 30 days. Can you please confirm you have developer edition and were able to access profile before ? I dont see any issue in my dev org.